# How can I link to an external OpenCart product page with the same product page ID as my site?

Tags: php, opencart

I would like to add an external link to the OpenCart product page - it can be anywhere on the page. I just want to link it to the same product page on an external site that has different options.

I tried to define it in the product controller file at breadcumbs but I don't have idea how can I change the default http value via PHP str_replace or something similar.

```
'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', $url . '&product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id']),
'href2' => $this->url->link('product/product', $url . '&product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id']),
```

I also tried to place this after the breadcrumb in product.tpl
like `<a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href2']; ?>"`

So this is working slightly - I just need to do the PHP replace or something better on the product page to point to the external domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than modifying the core PHP. You can do this easily inside your product.tpl file instead.

1 - Open /catalog/view/theme/default/product.tpl

2 - Add your link

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=<?php echo $this->request->get["product_id"]; ?>">Your Link</a>
```

What I am doing here is using $_GET to fetch your ProductID from the HEADER and that saves modifying the controllers.

Comment: Sorry but this is don't working. I would like to use the url rewrited version. So example i have a product on two opencart site.

site1/product-with-seo-url I would like to add a link to every product on site1. Like this site2/product-with-seo-url. The "product-with-seo-url" is dynamic depends from the product.

Comment: the solution above will work if you use Opencart's `request->get()` method.  Also, consider avoiding shorthand php tags as this will fail depending on server config.  `<a href="http://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=<?php echo $this->request->get["product_id"]; ?>">Your Link</a>`

Comment: Please update the answer with your suggestions thanks @billynoah